# Smarty get only first and last name

Tags: php, smarty

I'm learning Smarty and I would like to only display the first and last name of a person... Is it possible or is it better to use php for this?
Many thanks

Comment: You can manipulate array and string data with SMARTY.  So to answer your question - in general, you can modify a certain name (string) when being displayed via the DOM.  But you gotta post the code your dealing with and how its being loaded onto your page (i.e. you are loading an array of data to a section loop on to your page.)

Comment: Smarty is built on PHP. Smarty is only aware of the properties and values you give it, so yes, it's possible, but we need code examples, and what code you've got so far if you want help.

Comment: IMO Smarty is not worth using. Pseudo programming language inside PHP, heavily dropping performance.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys. I really have to use smarty in this case. All i have is a variable called $name that stores a fullname of a person :/ maybe php is the best way

Comment: Is there a space between the first and last name of data that is stored in the variable $name?

Comment: I use smarty and using correctly doesn't drop performance much. It makes keeping php and html separate easily. There are many template engines out there.

Comment: blachawk, yes... for example "Diogo Luis Antello de Sousa Loureiro Mendonça" (yes, my fullname) and only show "Diogo Mendonça" :)

Comment: It might require string manipulation. CODE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think this solution is viable? From my tests it is working:

```
{assign var="newname" value=" "|explode:$name}
{assign var=names_count value=$newname|@count} 
{if $names_count>2}
   {assign var=position value=$names_count-1}
   {$newname[0]} {$newname[$position]}
{else}
   {$name}
{/if}
```

Comment: If it works for you then its viable. I personally would have php do the manipulation if you have access to the PHP. Then just assign it to smarty. You know how your variable is setup and what's in it so we can only go off of what we are told.

Comment: Also sense you answered your own question, maybe you can upvote the other answers sense it helped you to get what you needed. :)

Comment: @Diogo Mendonca, good job on trying to discover your own smarty solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use PHP as a modifier on your page to explode your string data....

```
{" "|explode:$name}
```

or try this...

```
{assign var=nameparts value=" "|explode:$name}
```

Give it shot...But to be honest, you are better off doing that "explode" manipulation from the PHP source code, before that $name variable is loaded onto the HTML page.

**UPDATE**
Just to be safe with how you are using $name, you can setup a conditional...

```
{assign var=nameparts value=" "|explode:$name}

{if $nameparts[6] == 'Mendonça'}
  <p>then my name is {nameparts[0]} {nameparts[6]}.</p>   
{else}
  <p>we are dealing with a different name </p>
{/if}
```

..all within your HTML code that is using Smarty.

Comment: and then i get the first and the last element of the array ?

Comment: @DiogoMendonça give the code a shot and see if it works for you.  It's a little challenging to tell without being inside your system.

Comment: Yes conditional is good seeing that we can't see how is code is setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you really want to do it in Smarty.

```
{assign var="newname" value=" "|explode:$name}

{$newname[0]} {$newname[6]}
```

Update

OR.. What I would do is do it in PHP. Then assign it to smarty.

```
<?php
$arr = explode(" ", $name);
$fullname = $arr[0]." ".$arr[6];

$smarty->assign("fullname",$fullname);

?>
```

Then use `{$fullname}` in your template.

Comment: That looks very nice!

Comment: Thanks. @blachawk. I agree with you though, I'd do it in PHP then assign it.